# SQL: conditional IF after the where?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I am trying to query the below sample data, where if RowNum = 1 or ToUse = X.
However, I need to add an extra condition if the Account has both values (Example within the red square) then prioritize the column "ToUse", in the example below the account with id 6 have 6 records:

- 3 for property maintenance – 19734
- 3 for property maintenance – 19733

[image: SQL Question]

I want the result of the query to dismiss the 3 values for property maintenance – 19734

Below this image is the current query I am using

```
SELECT 
    Id,
    OpportunityId,
    OpportunityName,
    OpportunityStage,
    Email,
    RowNum,
    CreatedDate,
    ToUse,
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    Mobile,
    AccountName,
    AccOppotunityInProgress,
    AccTotalLoanPaid,
    AccTotalClosedLost,
    TotalOppsLoanFunded,
    Useractive,
    EmailOptOut,
    AccountID
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            con.Id AS [Id], 
            opp.Id AS [OpportunityId], 
            acc.Id AS [AccountID],
            opp.Name AS [OpportunityName],
            opp.CreatedDate AS [CreatedDate],
            opp.StageName AS [OpportunityStage],
            con.FirstName AS [FirstName],
            con.LastName AS [LastName],
            con.MobilePhone AS [Mobile],
            con.Useractive__c AS [Useractive],
            con.Email AS [Email],
            con.HasOptedOutOfEmail AS [EmailOptOut],
            acc.Name AS [AccountName],
            acc.Total_Opportunities_in_Progress__c AS [AccOppotunityInProgress],
            acc.Total_Loan_Paid__c AS [AccTotalLoanPaid],
            acc.Total_Closed_Lost__c AS [AccTotalClosedLost],
            opp.Total_Opportunities_Loan_Funded__c AS [TotalOppsLoanFunded],
            CASE WHEN opp.StageName = 'Loan Funded' 
            THEN 'X'
            ELSE 'FU'
            END AS ToUse,               
            row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY opp_con_role.ContactId ORDER BY opp.CreatedDate DESC) AS RowNum 
        From [Opportunitycontactrole] Opp_Con_Role
        INNER JOIN [Opportunity] opp
            On Opp_Con_Role.Opportunityid = Opp.Id 
        INNER JOIN [Contact] con
            On Opp_Con_Role.Contactid = Con.Id 
        INNER JOIN [account] acc
            ON acc.Id = opp.AccountId 
        WHERE con.Email IS NOT NULL OR con.MobilePhone IS NOT NULL
    ) sr ORDER BY sr.OpportunityName
```

This is the schema of the tables

[image: Schema of database]

The expected results, will be the table below without the lines that were highligted in yellow: (Rows 14 -17 should have been highlighted yello as well)

[image: sql-expected results]

EDIT:
When I add this partition I get the below result that is so closed to what i want however the record with the stage value of documents requested should be 1

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY opp_con_role.ContactId ORDER BY CASE WHEN opp.StageName = 'Loan Funded' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, opp.CreatedDate DESC) AS RowNum
```

[image: query result]

Comment: Sorry, did not get the question. Can you post desired results set?

Comment: @SlavaMurygin i will add the image shortly but as i mentioned, basically the same table but omitting the 3 records for property maintenance – 19734, so the red square should be 3 records instead of those 6, I am using heidisql, i havent been able to export into an excel

Comment: Maybe you need something like this:
"WHERE NOT (RowNum = 1 and ToUse != 'x') "

Comment: @SlavaMurygin, I have added a new image that hopefully helps clarifying the what i want as a result, I just tried your modification but it didnt work, it brought me more records that should be brought

Comment: What is the difference between lines 10 & 14? 
You are not telling the whole story

Comment: So, are you saying that you want an SQL that looks for either RowNum =1 or ToUse = 'X', BUT if there is an accountID that has rows that individually satisfy BOTH conditions, you only want to see the rows with ToUse = 'X'?  If that is the case, your followup example is off, and rows 14 through 17 should be yellow as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest altering the `order by` used to establish `RowNum` by including a `case expression` similar to that used for the `ToUse` column. This way I think you may be able to dispense with that column.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM (
    SELECT
        con.Id                                                                                    AS [Id]
      , opp.Id                                                                                    AS [OpportunityId]
      , acc.Id                                                                                    AS [AccountID]
      , opp.Name                                                                                  AS [OpportunityName]
      , opp.CreatedDate                                                                           AS [CreatedDate]
      , opp.StageName                                                                             AS [OpportunityStage]
      , con.FirstName                                                                             AS [FirstName]
      , con.LastName                                                                              AS [LastName]
      , con.MobilePhone                                                                           AS [Mobile]
      , con.Useractive__c                                                                         AS [Useractive]
      , con.Email                                                                                 AS [Email]
      , con.HasOptedOutOfEmail                                                                    AS [EmailOptOut]
      , acc.Name                                                                                  AS [AccountName]
      , acc.Total_Opportunities_in_Progress__c                                                    AS [AccOppotunityInProgress]
      , acc.Total_Loan_Paid__c                                                                    AS [AccTotalLoanPaid]
      , acc.Total_Closed_Lost__c                                                                  AS [AccTotalClosedLost]
      , opp.Total_Opportunities_Loan_Funded__c                                                    AS [TotalOppsLoanFunded]
      , CASE WHEN opp.StageName = 'Loan Funded' THEN 'X' ELSE 'FU' END                            AS ToUse
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY opp_con_role.ContactId
        ORDER BY CASE WHEN opp.StageName = 'Loan Funded' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, opp.CreatedDate DESC) AS RowNum
    FROM [Opportunitycontactrole] Opp_Con_Role
    INNER JOIN [Opportunity] opp ON Opp_Con_Role.Opportunityid = Opp.Id
    INNER JOIN [Contact] con ON Opp_Con_Role.Contactid = Con.Id
    INNER JOIN [account] acc ON acc.Id = opp.AccountId
    WHERE con.Email IS NOT NULL
    OR con.MobilePhone IS NOT NULL
) sr
WHERE RowNum = 1
ORDER BY
    sr.OpportunityName
```

Comment: Thank you that case inside the ROW_NUMBER() was what I wanted to do but I couldnt find a good tuorial Iguess for me is easier to see my own example up and running

Comment: Can I ask I found an issue, in one example it is also setting RowNum 1 to a record where the stage is not loan funded, I have added the image in my original question

Comment: I have to slightly ammend your suggestion using DENSE_RANK instead of ROW_NUMBER \

Comment: rank() or dense_rank()  can return multiple rows with the same value for a partition. Use row_number() if you need one and only one row with value of 1 for every partition. The ranking functions also perform more complex calculations than simple row numbering.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking what I think you are asking (which you may not be, as that would mean that rows 14-17 of your final example should also be in yellow), then you could try this:

(This is unoptimized, but just as a starting point)

```
Select * from assorted_tables
where ToUse = 'X'
or (RowNum = 1
    AND
    accountID not in (select accountID from assorted_tables
                     where toUse = 'X')
   )
```

Comment: Can i ask what is assorted_tables? yes you are right, rows 14-17 should be yellow too, I missed that. When i run your suggestion i get invalid object name assorted_table

Comment: You are specifying a select that joins 19 fields from 4 different tables.  I didn't want to write out all that, I just wanted to show the bit that was relevant (I.E. the where clause, with the "or" and the "not in")